# Ubuntu MATE 22.04 will only boot in recovery mode

Tags: boot, 22.04, amdgpu

Ubuntu MATE 22.04 will only boot in recovery mode.

I recently built a PC and went to put 22.04 on it. I could only get the USB to boot in safe graphics mode. Once installed, if I try to boot normally it stops at this line.

```
 [1.547289] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node.
```

I can boot to recovery mode and most things work fine, same as if I add "nomodeset" to the grub. But with nomodeset my PC detects my GPU as llvmpipe and will not run most of my games.

running $sudo lshw -c video

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:50000000-5fffffff memory:60000000-601fffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:60600000-6063ffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
   configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

Running `$sudo dmesg | grep -i amdgpu`

```
[    1.536641] [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
[    4.823677] [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
```

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated as I am running out of ideas.
Cheers.

[UPDATE] I think I fixed my issue. I went into the grub and and added
this line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.si_support=1 radeon.cik_support=1 amdgpu.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=0 amdgpu.dc=0 amdgpu.dpm=0 amdgpu.modeset=0"

This ignores amdgpu drivers and uses radeon legacy drivers (I think), for now it has solved my issue, the card is not pulling the same frame rates as it did on a previous machine and I would prefer to use the amdgpu drivers if possible.
Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, i had the same problem, i fixed it, after reading above post, with changing the "additional drivers" from  nvidia proprietary to xserver xorg video nouveau (open source).

Comment: The nouveau drivers are not for AMD GPUs, so this answer is unrelated to the question.